# CSS Change child element font color on parent hover

Tags: css

I'm trying to make it so when I :hover over a td, the span inside changes to white and the background of the td changes to blue. However, none of the similar questions seemed to help me on this.

First row of table for example:

```
<tbody>
     <tr>

        <td>
            <h4>
                <span>
                    <strong>Account Holder Collection Procedures</strong>
                </span>
            </h4>
        </td>

        <td>
            <h4>
                 <span>
                     <strong>AMVIR Help Sheet</strong>
                 </span>
            </h4>
        </td> 

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here's some CSS I've tried that **doesn't** work:

```
td:hover > h4 > span{
color: #fff !important;
}

td:hover > span{
color: #fff !important;
}

td:hover ~ span{
color: #fff !important;
}

td:hover + span{
color: #fff !important;
}

td:hover span{
color: #fff !important;
}
```

This makes the td background the right color, but will only change the span color if you mouse over the span, not the td:

```
td:hover{
background: #0073a5;
}

span:hover{
color: #fff !important;
}
```

This is what the above CSS looks like if I put my mouse on the td, but not the span:

[image]

**Solution:**

```
div[class*="et_pb_tab_"] td:hover span{
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: Your CSS seems entirely dependent on this class `.et_pb_tab_0` which I see nowhere in the HTML.

Comment: This is a snipet from a bigger more complicated module. It's not relevant as I am able to style the things in the html with this CSS. I just trimmed the fat to save some space. My problem has to do with syntax, not the way the example looks.

Comment: Depending on what other styles you already have defined, `td:hover span {color: #fff !important;}` should get you there

Comment: @DylanGrove Don't add your solution to your question but as answer :) If you are looking for an answer the question is not the first place to look at ;)

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Sorry, but the answer only partially answered it.

Comment: Then write a better one. But don't update your question. That is not what the question is for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSS will become this:

```
td:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}

td:hover span {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing this: div[class*="et_pb_tab_"] td:hover span{ color: #fff !important; }   thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
.et_pb_tab_0 td:hover h4{ color: #fff !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're not mentioning the parent of the `<span>` which will affect it when you hover it. In our case the `<td>`. 
It should always be like this:

```
.parent:hover .child {
   /* ... */
}
```

So your CSS needs to be edited to:

```
td:hover{
background: #0073a5;
}

td:hover span{
color: #fff !important;
}
```

You can see that it matches the format mentioned above!

This is not related to the question, but you can add `transition: all .1s ease;` to the <`td>` and `<span>` for a smoother animation